# Select people with a given surname from database

Tags: sqlite

I do the following to get the population in a set of districts for a given year:

```
SELECT Year, County, District, Count(*) FROM census_data group by Year, County, District where Year = ?;
```

Then I do the following many thousands of times to get the population in each district for each surname I am interested in:

```
SELECT Year, County, District, COUNT(*) FROM census_data where Year = ? and Surname = ? group by Year, County, District;
```

There are 8 million rows in my db covering two specific years. There are roughly 40 counties and a county typically has a few hundred districts.

Should I add an index on my table to speed up the above queries as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX surname_index ON census_data (surname);
```

My thinking is that since generally speaking there are not many people with a given surname then it should be enough just to index it. Or would you recommend something else? I could also change the query to:

```
SELECT Year, County, District, COUNT(*) FROM census_data where Surname = ? group by Year, County, District;
```

for I am usually interested in both years anyway. When doing queries, how do I see if my index is being used?

Comment: I would say, yes index surname.  But you might also create a composite index on both Year AND surname. In all cases, the performance should guide your choice. If your query take too long to execute, you should create indexes, if it is fine, don't do anything. The major downsides of creating indexes are : your INSERTS will take longer, and you need additional storage. Your very last question is the key to make the right decision, look at the **EXPLAIN PLAN** of your query to see what happens with the indexes --> Read this carefully https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html

Comment: I feel like you could probably do the whole surname counts as a single query instead of thousands.

Comment: @Thomas G I dont need to insert. The db is finalised.

Comment: @Shawn How would I do this query: "SELECT Year, County, District, COUNT(*) FROM census_data where Year = ? and Surname = ? group by Year, County, District;" for the 1000 most common surnames in the db?

Comment: Start by putting the names you're interested in into a temp table you can join on (a subquery works too, but an indexed table is likely to be more efficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would use an index on the columns you're grouping by. Like I mentioned in the comments, I'd also use one query that produces all the desired rows over 1000 queries that produce a fragment of the total apiece. Make the database do all that work only once. Since you mentioned the names you're interested in are the 1000 most common ones, not random names, that actually makes it a bit easier.

The following demonstrates two slightly different approaches to getting the count per `(year, county, district, surname)` of the most common surnames overall:

First, populate a table with some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE census(year INTEGER, county TEXT, district TEXT, surname TEXT);
INSERT INTO census VALUES
       (2012, 'Lake', 'West', 'Smith'),
       (2012, 'Lake', 'West', 'Jones'),
       (2012, 'Lake', 'West', 'Smith'),
       (2012, 'Lake', 'West', 'Washington'),
       (2012, 'Lake', 'West', 'Washington'),
       (2012, 'Lake', 'East', 'Smith'),
       (2012, 'Lake', 'East', 'Jackson'),
       (2012, 'Williams', 'Downtown', 'Jones'),
       (2012, 'Williams', 'Downtown', 'McMaster'),
       (2012, 'Williams', 'West Side', 'Jones'),
       (2012, 'Williams', 'West Side', 'Jones');
CREATE INDEX census_idx ON census(year, county, district, surname);
```

(Your real data will, of course, have a lot more rows, and presumably more columns. Depending on space constraints, you might want to drop surname from the index, at the cost of a slower query. With all four columns in the index, it's a *covering index* for the queries below and the actual table rows never get accessed. With just the first three (Or two, or one), it'll need temporary b-trees for the grouping, and more table accesses.).

Approach one: Populate a temporary table with the 1000 most common names overall, and use that table in a join to restrict the results to just those names:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE names(name TEXT PRIMARY KEY) WITHOUT ROWID;
INSERT INTO names
 SELECT surname FROM census GROUP BY surname ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1000;    
SELECT year, county, district, surname, count(*) as number
FROM census AS c
JOIN names AS n ON c.surname = n.name
GROUP BY year, county, district, surname
ORDER BY year, county, district, count(*) DESC, surname;
```

Approach two: Do the same thing, but a subquery instead of a table for the most common names:

```
SELECT year, county, district, surname, count(*) as number
FROM census AS c
JOIN (SELECT surname AS name FROM census GROUP BY surname ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1000) AS n ON c.surname = n.name
GROUP BY year, county, district, surname
ORDER BY year, county, district, count(*) DESC, surname;
```

Both produce:

```
year        county      district    surname     number    
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
2012        Lake        East        Jackson     1         
2012        Lake        East        Smith       1         
2012        Lake        West        Smith       2         
2012        Lake        West        Washington  2         
2012        Lake        West        Jones       1         
2012        Williams    Downtown    Jones       1         
2012        Williams    Downtown    McMaster    1         
2012        Williams    West Side   Jones       2
```

If you're going to run this query a lot in a session, the first approach will be faster - it only has to build the list of most common names once, while the second one has to do it every time the query is run. It is, however, more involved because it takes multiple SQL statements. For a single run, benchmarking the two on a decent sized dataset is the best guide, of course.